# Rollup does not exit

Tags: typescript, rollup

I use rollup to bundle typescript code, but it does not exit after the target file is generated.

I have the config like this

```js
import rollupTypescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only'

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: 'dist/index.iife.js',
      format: 'iife',
      name: 'plotter',
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    rollupTypescript(),
    css({ ouput: 'dist/index/css' }),
  ],
}
```

And I can see the output as terminal
[image]

It tells that the file is created, but the rollup process does not exit.

Typescript: 4.4.2

Rollup: 2.26.4

@rollup/plugin-typescript: 8.2.5

Is there anything I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The config is missing a closing `]` (to close `output`) and `}` (to close the config). Not sure this is the problem but is the config here minimally complete and accurate?

Comment: @stealththeninja Thank for pointing that out. It was a typo. Sorry for that, I should have been more careful. But that does not cause my problem. The config is closed in my codes. And here it's also edited.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Rollup to the latest version (2.56.3), it works well. I don't know what the problem was when I had the rollup@2.26.4 and typescript@4.4.2 versions.

Comment: Same issue with rollup 2.56.3